# Flutter - How to calculate the average number of rating for each product on listview

Tags: php, json, api, flutter

I have two database tables, one with the list of "product" and another with "ratings" of the products. When users submit their rating user ID is sent along with the user rating and review in "ratings" table. I have my PHP rest API as below which returns a list of ratings from users based on content ID 3,5,4,2 etc. How do I display the average rating of all users per product on the list view in my flutter code with SmoothStarRating. Below is my Flutter code and my PHP rest api:

````
require 'database.php';
$db_connection = new Database();
$conn = $db_connection->dbConnection();

if(isset($_GET['id']))
{
    //IF HAS ID PARAMETER
    $post_id = filter_var($_GET['id'], FILTER_VALIDATE_INT,[
        'options' => [
            'default' => 'all_posts',
            'min_range' => 1
        ]
    ]);
}
else{
    $post_id = 'all_posts';
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `Ratings` where deal_id = '$post_id' "; 

$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);

$stmt->execute();

if($stmt->rowCount() > 0){
    // CREATE POSTS ARRAY
    $posts_array = [];
    
    while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        
        $post_data = [$row['ratings']];

                           $post_data1 = implode(" ",$post_data);  

        array_push($posts_array, $post_data1);
    }
    echo json_encode($posts_array, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);

}
else{
    echo json_encode(['message'=>'No post']);
}

?>


Future<String> getRatings() async {
    setState(() {
      isLoading = true;
    });
    try {
      final result = await InternetAddress.lookup('google.com');
      if (result.isNotEmpty && result[0].rawAddress.isNotEmpty) {
        print('connected');
        debugPrint("emirate connect");

        String url =
            "http://mysite/shopper_api/view_rating.php?id=" +
                content.id;

        var res = await http
            .get(Uri.encodeFull(url), headers: {"Accept": "application/json"});
        resRating = json.decode(res.body);

        debugPrint("rating url:$url");

        setState(() {
          data = resRating;
          isLoading = false;
        });

        print(resRating);
        debugPrint("ratings:$resRating");

        return "Sucess";
      } else {
        throw Exception('Failed to load profile');
      }
    } on SocketException catch (_) {
      print('not connected');
      setState(() => isLoading = false);

      showDialog(
          context: context,
          barrierDismissible: false,
          builder: (context) {
            return CupertinoAlertDialog(
              //title: Text('Internet Error!'),
              content: Text(
                'Check your internet connection and press Ok.',
                style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'Montserrat'),
              ),
              actions: <Widget>[
                FlatButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.pushReplacement(
                          context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(
                              builder: (BuildContext ctx) => Maps(content)));
                    },
                    child: Text(
                      'Ok',
                      style:
                          TextStyle(color: colorPink, fontFamily: 'Montserrat'),
                    )),
              ],
            );
          });
    }
  }

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
var rating = 1.0;


return Scaffold(
                 child:Padding(
                                                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                                    bottom: 0),
                                                child: SmoothStarRating(
                                                    allowHalfRating: false,
                                                    onRatingChanged: (v) {
                                                      setState(() {
                                                        this.rating = v;
                                                      });
                                                    },
                                                    starCount: 5,
                                                    rating: rating,
                                                    size: 20.0,
                                                    filledIconData: Icons.star,
                                                    halfFilledIconData:
                                                        Icons.star_half,
                                                    color: colorGreen,
                                                    borderColor: colorGreen,
                                                    spacing: 0.0)),

    );} ```
````

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I was able to work out a perfect way to get the average rating by joining the two table which is the table for "product" and "rating" and comparing the ID of the "product" to the ID of "product" stored in the "rating" table and get the total average rating with below sql query:

```
$sql = "product.id, AVG(rating.rated) AS rated FROM product LEFT JOIN rating ON product.id = rating.product_id GROUP BY product.id",
```